# Do luck bonuses stack?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, stacking

I know that usually you pick the highest value bonus of the same type, but I see a lot of D&D threads where people are stacking their luck bonuses.

Let's say I cast

- [Divine Favor](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/divineFavor.htm) (You gain a +1 luck bonus on attack and weapon damage rolls for every three caster levels you have (at least +1, maximum +3))
- [Prayer](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/prayer.htm) (You and each of your allies gain a +1 luck bonus on attack rolls, weapon damage rolls, saves, and skill checks)
- [Recitation](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101074656/http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/article.asp?x=dnd/sb/sb20021103a) (Your allies gain a +2 luck bonus to AC, on attack rolls, and on saving throws, or a +3 luck bonus if they worship the same deity as you)

Will I get only one luck bonus at all (from only one spell), all luck bonuses (but not stacking, only the highest values from each category, like +3 saves and attack from Recitation, +3 on damage rolls from Divine Favor (if max +3)), or all luck bonuses (and they stack with each other)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Luck bonuses do not stack with each other

From the SRD:

> Luck Modifier
> A luck modifier represents good (or bad) fortune. Multiple luck bonuses on the same character or object do not stack. Only the highest luck bonus applies.

However, **bonuses of the same type, but to different scores, coexist**. For example, if all three of those spells were affecting you as cast by a ninth level caster, you would have:

- A +3 luck bonus to attack rolls and weapon damage rolls
- A +2 luck bonus to AC and saving throws
- A +1 luck bonus to Skill Checks

Comment: thanks, got the point, though if i am the caster or worship the same deity as the caster, i will have +3 to AC i guess