# In-world justification for stacking rules?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, stacking

Inspired by [this question on World Building](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/210290/50), I'm curious if the bonus stacking rules from various editions of D&D have ever had an in-world justification published.

From what I've found, there's basically been two types of rules:

- Bonuses of the same type don't stack (except for some edition-specific named exceptions): D&D 3e,3.5,4e; PF 1e,2e
- Everything stacks, unless the source specifically specifies otherwise (and many things specify otherwise): OD&D, AD&D, D&D 5e

There's generally good *mechanical* reasons for the first kind, and *thematic* reasons for the second, but I've never actually seen an in-world justification for any of it. Has any official rules source (not author commentary) ever explained what characters think about why [*bracers of defense/armor* don't stack with mundane armor, but a *ring of protection* does](https://forum.rpg.net/index.php?threads/ac-in-first-ed-ad-d-what-stacks-and-what-doesnt.738375/)?  Or why three different spells have [overlapping but not stacking effects](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31956/do-luck-bonuses-stack)?  Or do they just say "it's magic, it doesn't have to make sense"?

In lieu of an official rules publication addressing it, an answer from official D&D-based fiction (such as the Forgotten Realms or Dragonlance novel series) could also work here.  Since those are written from an in-world viewpoint, it would be an example of how at least *one* character understood it.  (It's plausible that the in-world justification is different across different settings, but I would be surprised if it came up enough that there'd actually be a difference.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because which is chosen is a [Designer Intent question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8657/303069) in disguise. In World justifications would be Idea Generation and Opinion based. As a result: This is Off Topic.

Comment: @Trish If this question is asking specifically about whether the rules, modules, magazines, and the like have ever given in-universe explanations or in-universe conceptualizations of the stacking rules, this question is on-topic.

Comment: @Trish My [edit](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/190888/2) should put away any suspicion that this might be an off optic developer intent question.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning that up, @ThomasMarkov.  I wouldn't say "no" to a designer's commentary on it, but I understand why unofficial and/or speculative sources like that aren't valid here.   I did add novelizations as another option, though, since that seems like another reasonable, _published_ source of thematic information.

Comment: In general, I would say that the "in-world" justification is simply *verisimilitude*. And I wrote an answer expanding on that, but on further consideration it's probably off-topic here, since I know of no published sources to cite for it.

Answer (score 8):

### Stacking itself is a part of mechanics, not a in-world thing

I've never seen in-world explanations of (not) stacking in the rules, and I don't think there can be any. Stacking is adding together things like AC, DC, modifiers, and other numbers which nave pure mechanical meaning - hence stacking  itself is a part of game mechanics.

AC doesn't exist in-world. It is just an abstraction for a vague concept that armor can protect you. It doesn't actually simulate any in-world properties of armor. It isn't meant to be realistic.

The same is true for stacking. It is just an oversimplified abstraction for a broader principle that some things can have synergy. It isn't meant to be realistic or have any in-world explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure this really addresses it.   Sure, the numeric values and such aren't something that characters are aware of, but "I put this on and the magic doesn't work for me because I also have a chain shirt" seems like something they'd be aware of.

Comment: @Bobson I think this does answer the question, or at least come as close as is likely possible. There's a good chance that they aren't aware that a specific ring isn't providing a noticeable benefit because of their chain shirt because in the real world such things are hard to tease apart. Sometimes in the real world an arrow might pierce chainmail and sometimes it wouldn't due to a whole plethora of factors. To the extent the in world characters are aware of it, they would be aware of it in a much more complex system of what has synergy and what doesn't meaning there will be no one answer.

Comment: @Bobson This answer is a fine example of challenging the frame of the question, or to put it differently, highlighting the erroneous assumptions embedded in the question. More commentary [on that can be found here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6842/22566)

Comment: @Bobson Many fantasy settings specifically state that iron is destructive to magic.  This is an extension of the idea from folklore that magical creatures are specifically vulnerable to cold-iron weapons.  So, many settings do actually justify why you can't cast magic in metal armor, or in some systems, why you can't even have an iron based weapon as a wizard.

Comment: @Bobson let's take a chain shirt for example. It has 13 base AC. If AC would stack, wearing two chain shirts one over another would give you 26 AC. This makes you almost invulnerable and is ridiculous, but it would happen *because the mechanics work that way*. So the rules just state "base AC don't stack". This doesn't mean wearing two chain shirts have no consequences in-world at all. It just means such consequences are not supported my this particular game mechanics.

Comment: @enkryptor I believe a person's natural AC is 10 (+dex) so the chainmail is only granting 3 AC so double is 16 AC. Chain mail has a strength requirement to carry so a DM could rule that, sure you can wear two, but the weight gives you disadvantage on a ton of stuff because you'll be incredibly sluggish.

Comment: This answer could really use a rules quote to support statement like *"AC doesn't exist in-world"*. I think there even is one in the books, but CBA to dig it out myself.

Comment: @enkryptor I think two chain shirts is a bad example. AC is not just about how hard to penetrate the single armor piece is, but how hard to penetrate the overall defense is. A chain shirt has its AC from protecting a limited region of the body well, while leaving the rest unprotected. Protecting the same region with another chain shirt really shouldn't increase AC (if anything, it should make unprotected areas easier to hit due to constricted movement). So it's not comparable to the question why a magic ring and s chain shirt don't stack.

Comment: @RHS actually, this was exactly the point. Although chain shirt has "AC 13" in its stats block, you can't simply add AC by adding more chain shirts. I could choose another non-stacking game statistics, but I chose AC as an exaggerated and the most obvious example.

Comment: @enkryptor My point is that an obvious example such as this doesn't give any insights on why something like a chain shirt plus a magic ring shouldn't stack.

Comment: @RHS can you think of a better example? The point is: items don't stack, numbers stack. Items are in-world things, number are not. Simultaneously using more items doesn't automatically mean addition of numbers.

Comment: @enkryptor I don't think anyone is disputing that. But that's just restating the premise of the question. The premise is that *some* in-world items could be better in combination than in isolation, but the numbers (which aren't in-world things) don't reflect that. The question was: Is there an official source that reconciles narrative and mechanics by explaining in in-world terms why these items don't work better in combination.